How can I apply a transformation to a JSON file during build in Visual Studio?
I have a project A (.NET Core) that is referenced by a project B. In project A, I have a JSON file that needs to be updated at compile time (to replace some values) and I would like the JSON file in the build output of project B to be replaced as well.
Sln : 
    Project A
        file.json (build action : none, copy always)

    Project B
        References
            Project A

Content of file A before build is something like :
{
    key : {{this will be replaced during build}}
}

After build it is something like :
{
    key : "VALUE"
}

So far, I tried with post build events in Project A and this works well for the bin folder of project A, but in the bin folder of project B, I have the file.json before string replacement.
I tried disabling the accelerated build as I thought this might be the issue but it does not seem to change the output.
I also tried with a msbuild task :
  <UsingTask TaskName="TestReplace" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
      <ParameterGroup />
      <Task>
          <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
          <Using Namespace="System" />
          <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
          <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
              <![CDATA[
var path = "file.json";
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
fileContent = fileContent.Replace("{{this will be replaced during build}}", "VALUE");
File.WriteAllText(path, fileContent);
]]>
          </Code>
      </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="TestReplace" AfterTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
      <TestReplace />
  </Target>

But with the same result (JSON is OK in output folder for project A, but not for project B)
Is this the intended behavior or did I misconfigure anything? And if this is indeed the intended behavior, what would be the recommended way to achieve the string replacement both in project A and in all the projects that depend on it?
I looked into Single File Generators but it sounds like a complicated solution, and I would prefer to avoid installing a custom extension on all devs machines.
Thanks !
edit : for anyone wondering, I ended up doing something like this :
<None Update="file.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
    <None Update="tmp\file.json" Link="file.json">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="do something that write from file.json to tmp/file.json" />
</Target>

and I added tmp/ to the .gitignore

Transform the copy of the "file.json" that is in the output directory, not the original file in the project directory. (Or, put another way, the build shouldn't make changes to version-controlled source files.)

That's what I am doing now but it is not working for dependant projects

In the example code that you provided: The TestReplace task has a hard-coded path of "file.json". That path will be interpreted as relative to the project directory. The TestReplace task is run in the TestReplace target which is run after the CopyFilesToOutputDirectory target. So, the original file is copied to the output directory and then the original file in the project directory is transformed. Projects which reference project A will copy from the output directory.

Mmm, my bad, I simplified my code too much before posting but the path to file.json is actually a path in the output folder.

The problem is that Project B doesn't actually copy files from Project A's output folder.
During the execution project B's GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target, the json is being picked up directly from A and added to B's _TransitiveItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory list (which is later dumped in B's output).
What you can do instead is ensure that the file added to A's <None> list is already transformed, not the original file. So, hook your target earlier into the build process, perform the transformation, then add the transformed file into None.

So you are suggesting something like a pre build task where I generate a new file "filereplaced.json" that is probably in the git ignore and I should ignore file.json afterwards during build to only use filereplaced ? I'll look into it and revert, thanks.

Something like that. Add the task earlier, then within your target add the newly generated file into  early enough so it gets picked up by the rest of the build process.

<Target ...> <TestReplace /> <ItemGroup> <None ... /> </ItemGroup> </Target>

I accepted your answer because doing a pre build variabilization tasks does indeed work but I'm not sure I'll end up doing that though, it does not feel right.
